# How to save a stored procedure into Azure SQL Server

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

I am writing a test stored procedure on visual studio code (I cannot install SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio as I don't think its available on Linux Ubuntu).

[image: storedProcedure1]

I need to save this stored procedure on my Azure SQL Server because I am adding stored procedure activity to my pipeline in Azure Data Factory, and I have to select the store procedure while connecting to the Azure SQL Server.

[image: storedProc2]

Here is my Azure SQL Server where I can find the system stored procedure but I cannot find the place where I can save my stored procedure or queries to the SQL Server.

[image: storeproc3]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a solution. I need to be able to execute successfully the stored procedure first on my vscode. Then; after I see the stored procedure that I wrote appeared on Azure SQL server.